# "&lang" misinterpreted in URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser, anchor

I am developing for **javascript disabled** phones. My code looks like this

```
<a href="someurl?var=a&lang=english">Link 1</a>
<a href="someurl?lang=english&var=a">Link 2</a>
```

But the browser interprets the URL as -

```
someurl?var=a%e2%8c%a9=english         (Link 1, incorrect)
someurl?lang=english&var=a             (Link 2 works just fine !)
```

It seems like `&lang=english` is being converted to `a%e2%8c%a9=english`

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: what id you did it like this: `<a href="someurl?var=a&amp;lang=english">Link 1</a>`

Comment: Is this usual behaviour in every browser? I dont have any problems in Firefox 31

Comment: This is related to a very low end browser on a phone.

Comment: &lang is read as an HTML entity (improperly terminated, there should
 be a semicolon after). Any instance of "ampersand word (semicolon)" is
 parsed as an entity. To avoid that, you must escape the ampersand:
 "&amp;lang="
 Here the entity "&amp;" is correctly parsed as the code for an ampersand.

Comment: Your `<a>` HTML is invalid until you change that ampersand into an entity reference - on _all_ browsers.

Comment: @halfer Incorrect as far as I can tell, the ampersand should just work fine except when a 4-2 letter string and a ; is followed by it.

Comment: @Eater: can you find a sample of code that shows an unescaped `&` in a URL is valid at the W3C validator? Every time I've validated HTML it has complained about this issue.

Comment: @halfer I meant as in "browser"-valid instead of W3C valid. tbh W3C can go find a bathtub in this case. Im not gonna replace all my `&`'s by `&amp;`'s. but thats my opinion

Comment: @EaterOfCode, well, you can write invalid HTML if you want, but the above question is the result of that policy! That this is invalid HTML surprised me too, when I first found out about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HTML, the `&` character represents the start of a character reference.

If you try to specify an invalid character reference, then browsers will perform error recovery and treat it as an ampersand instead.

From the HTML DTD:

```
<!ENTITY lang     CDATA "&#9001;" -- left-pointing angle bracket = bra,
                                 U+2329 ISOtech -->
```

… so `&lang` is not an invalid character reference.

To include an ampersand character as data, use the character reference for an ampersand: `&amp;`

Answer (score 5):

By [HTML 4.01 rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), the `&lang` entity reference denotes the character U+2329 LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET “〈”. In UTF-8 encoding, that character is represented as 0xE2 0x8C 0xA9, and therefore in a URL, it gets %-encoded as `a%e2%8c%a9`.

Nowadays, most browsers don’t work that way. Specifically, in a URL, the reference `&lang` is not recognized when followed by an equals sign `=` (even though it is valid HTML 4.01 in that context).

To deal with browsers that may follow the old rules, as well as in order to comply with syntax rules independently of HTML version, escape each occurrence of the ampersand “&” as `&amp;`—it is safest to do this for all occurrences of “&” as a data character, in attribute values and elsewhere.

Depending on the server-side software that processes the URL when they have been followed, you might be able to use an unproblematic character like “;” instead of “&” as a separator.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp (linked by w3 from http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html) explains it.

`&` marks the start of a so called `entity`. Entities are for example `&euro;` (€), `&lt;` (<),..

If you now put in the URL `&lang`, this throws an error in any validator, because its not a valid entity. The browser is then escaping this sequence.

Solution:

You have to escape the `&` by its own entity: `&amp;` so the URL will look like:

```
<a href="someurl?var=a&amp;lang=english">Link 1</a>
```